# vuejs css transition not working on mobile chrome

Tags: vue.js, animation, mobile, transition

I am trying to create a mobile page transition in vue that should look like a native IOS app page transitions for my hybrid app.

To achieve this, I have created a css transition in vue.

It works fine on my pc and on mobile safari but no transition is shown on my IPhone mobile chrome.

The animation can be found here https://codepen.io/patrick2009/pen/eYRqMap

This is the full code:

```
  <div id="app" class="effect-content-push">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button @click="openOverlay">ANIMATE</button>
    </div>
    <transition name="content-push">
      <div class="overlay content-push" v-if="open">
        <button
          type="button"
          @click.prevent="closeOverlay"
          class="overlay-close"
        >
          Close
        </button>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() { 
    return { 
      effect: 'content-push', 
      open: false, 
      overlay: null, 
      container: null } 
  }, 
  mounted() { 
    this.overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
    this.container = document.querySelector('.container'); 
  }, 
  methods: {
    openOverlay() { 
        this.container.classList.add('overlay-open'); 
        this.open = true;
      }, 
    closeOverlay() { 
      this.container.classList.remove('overlay-open'); 
      this.open = false; 
      } 
    }
};
</script>
<style>
html, body { height: 100%; } 
body { background: #fff; } 
#app { height: 100%; }
/* Overlay style */ 
  .overlay { 
    position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; 
  } 
  .effect-content-push .container .overlay-open
 { 
    transition: transform 0.5s; 
    transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
.effect-content-push .overlay { 
  background: rgba(153,204,51,1); 
} 
.content-push-enter, .content-push-leave-to {
  background: rgba(153,204,51,1); 
  transform: translateX(+100%); 
  }
.content-push-enter-active, .content-push-leave-active { 
  transition: transform 0.5s; 
}
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As I am fairly new to vue, there might already be a slide transition I could use, if this is the case then don't hesitate to point me to the correct library/codepen I could use.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem in mobile Chrome as well. Were you able to find a solution? 

I made a smaller codepen that shows animation working at 1500ms, but failing at 1000ms (works fine on desktop, but try on mobile). This is the behavior I see in my app as well.

https://codepen.io/definitelynotamachine/pen/JjrxZYj

Answer (score 0):

Take this for what it's worth, but after replicating the issue in codepen with a simple slower animation that works and simple faster one that doesn't, I was able to fix this by killing the Chrome app on iOS and restarting it ‍♂️

https://codepen.io/definitelynotamachine/pen/JjrxZYj

```
// SLOW TRANSITION

.crossfade-1-enter,
.crossfade-1-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.crossfade-1-leave-active,
.crossfade-1-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1500ms;
}

// FAST TRANSITION

.crossfade-2-enter,
.crossfade-2-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.crossfade-2-leave-active,
.crossfade-2-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1000ms;
}
```

My first clue was the official Vue transition doc page not showing working transitions, either.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a bug in iOS Chrome running on (IIRC) iOS 14.3 or later. It seems to remain unaddressed after two years. I suggest opening a ticket using “Report an Issue” from the Chrome menu if this is impacting you.